# Update JS function's parameter within React after component state change using Select element

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am having trouble updating my calendar's dates using my working js function "generateWeekDivs(currentMonth, currentYear)", as I am selecting the month (currentMonth) from the drop down and wanting to regenerate my component's view.

Currently I am passing the month and year into the js function by hard coding, but I want to let the state change from the onChange() function within the select element determine when the js function would update with new values. However, the onChange() function is async, and so the state value would not update till react rerenders, but I need my js function to be ran every time the state updates. I do not know how to keep track of the changes and passing the new state values into my js function correctly due to the async nature.

The "generateWeekDivs(currentMonth, currentYear)" does all of the correct calculations and returns the corresponding row divs with day values. So all I need to do is figure out how to sync the parameter updates with the onChange() of the Select element, and that should solve the issue...

[Component frontend view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rmOz.jpg)

I tried useEffect, but that does not allow me to place the "generateWeekDivs(currentMonth, currentYear)" function within my "weekHolders" div, which then generates a number of div rows that contain the correct date values...

I then tried adding a

value and put currentMonth into it to see if that changes correctly when Select option is changed. With that, everytime I change the Select element's option value, that

element's innerHTML updates correctly... but I don't know how to do the same if the updated value should go into the parameters for the JS function, and not just simply re-rendering a p tag's value.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../Stylings/Calendar.css';
import {getYear, getMonthNum, getMonthName, generateWeekDivs, generateMonths, generateYears} from '../Calendar/DateFunctions.js';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function Calendar() {
    const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(getMonthNum);
    const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(getYear);
    console.log(getMonthName(getMonthNum()));

    return (
        <div className='calendarContainer'>
            <div className="titleToggle"> 
                <select 
                    className="selectMonths"
                    defaultValue={getMonthName(currentMonth)}
                    onChange={(e) => setCurrentMonth(e.target.value)}
                >
                    {generateMonths()}
                </select>
                <select 
                    className="selectYears"
                    defaultValue={currentYear}
                    // onChange={this.changeYear}
                >
                    {generateYears(currentYear)}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div className='weekHeader'>
                <h5>Mon</h5><h5>Tue</h5><h5>Wed</h5><h5>Thu</h5><h5>Fri</h5><h5>Sat</h5><h5>Sun</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="weekHolders">
                {generateWeekDivs(currentMonth, currentYear)} {/*wanting to correctly update currentMonth and currentYear everytime setCurrentMonth() changes*/}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Calendar;
```

Comment: Please replace images of code with a text-based [mcve].